# What is an appropriate naming convention for a merge function's parameters?

Tags: c++, naming-conventions

I am writing a C++ function that takes two Foo objects and adds the elements of the first into the second one, like so:

```
MyFunction(const Foo& a, Foo* b) {
  for (int i = 0; i < a.bar_count(); i++) {
    b->Bar(i) = b->HasBar(i) ? Average(a.Bar(i), b->Bar(i)) : a.Bar(i);
  }
}
```

This is a toy example, obviously, but my point is: what should be the names of `MyFunction`, `a` and `b`? My first thought was something like `MergeFoo` but then I am not sure what to name the parameters because my best thought is something like `merger` and `mergee` which seems dumb.

What are good names for `a`, `b`, and `MyFunction` so that the API will be clear for users of this function?

Comment: Maybe `operator+` would be a better function to use in this case.

Comment: Use names that indicate what `a` and `b` represent.

Comment: If your function isn't doing the classic merge algorithm then don't call it merge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After considering all the options, I decided the best choice is something like `AverageBarsInPlace(const Foo& new_bars, Foo* existing_bars);`. I like the "InPlace" suffix from Yakk. I agree with may responses that say "don't call it `Merge` unless it's actually doing a merge".

However, my real take-away from the lack of consensus on this question is: this function has a poorly defined scope. I should break the function into more cohesive chunks, such as one function to do merging, and another to do averaging.

Answer (score 2):

I'd call them `merge()`, `src` and `dest`, but there are of course other good names.

Comment: That was my first thought, but I was afraid `dest` was misleading, since that implies it takes a "blank" Foo, even though it is actually involved in the computation.

Comment: @RobertMartin: To me, `dest` has no such connotations (especially given that the function is called `merge()`), but I can't speak for others...

Answer (score 0):

That looks like an inplace `zip`-then-average operation.  ( http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip )

So instead of indexed access, have iterator access.  Then http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/iterator/doc/zip_iterator.html zip the two, then http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/iterator/doc/transform_iterator.html transform the result back into the first iterator (conditional average).

This does get a bit annoying to write in C++.

iterator over `boost::optional<bar>`, zipped into a pair, then a `boost::optional<bar>` is produced by taking one or averaging if both exist.

So, `left.ZipThenAverageInPlace( right )`?

Answer (score 0):

`from` and `into` seem like they might be appropriate, but personally I'd make it a method of your `Foo` class. That means there's no ambiguous parameter order, no inconvenient parameter naming, etc... `Foo::merge(const Foo& other_foo)`

Incidentally, I'd consider calling it something different. Merging for me suggests that the end result is the set union of the original components, whereas you're doing some sort of moving average computation, or similar. I don't have a good alternative name to suggest, because I don't know the actual purpose or functionality of `Foo`, `Bar` or  `Average`, so that'll have to be up to you!

Comment: I would love to make it a method on the `Foo` class. Unfortunately, I can't modify the `Foo` class so that's not an option. Alas.

Comment: @RobertMartin I guess the operator overloading option is available to you... I'd be very hesitant to do that unless the semantics of the "merge" closely match the standard meaning of the operator (`+=` would be reasonable for a "set union" style merge, to my mind).

Answer (score 0):

A common C++ naming convention would be `lhs` and `rhs` .That means left-hand-side and right-hand side. Usually, if the function modifies one of its parameters, that would be `lhs`. So in your example:

```
void MyFunction(Foo& lhs, const Foo& rhs);
```

Note that the order is swapped from your example.

For example, see the boost library, e.g. this: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/utility/operators.htm

Comment: Thanks. The order is swapped because I am using the "outputs go last" convention for function arguments.

Answer (score 0):

what a maintainer would expect from 'merge' on container like objects would be functionality according to [merge](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/merge/). what you want to accomplish is in the STL named [transform](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/transform/) with a binary operator named 'average'. if you don't use STL algorithm I'd name the function 'average' to avoid 'merge'

Answer (score 0):

One could define a merge function as this: An instance absorbs elements released by another instance. So this leads me to use the parameter names `absorber` and `releaser`

In PHP this result in the following function definition:

`public function merge(ClassName $absorber, ClassName $releaser): void`